# Issues setting up DVWA for SQLMAP

Tags: mysql, dvwa

I am starting on sqlmap, and have dvwa for practicing web app penetration.

I am having the error "Could not connect to the database - please check the config file."

Not sure what the problem is but I have been searching. Nothing seems to be working. I have mySQL running on Linux, created a database.

Comment: I assume your sqlmap is connecting to dvwa and not your local mysql instance? We might be able to help better if you included the sqlmap command. We can't help you blind.

Comment: Usually i set up XAMPP for windows or linux, then set up. Although using OWASP Broken Web Apps VM is MUCH easier and has more cool stuff OWASP Broken Web Apps VM: http://sourceforge.net/projects/owaspbwa/files/ XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
-hope this helps

Comment: There is a database configuration file at config/config.inc.php. It has the database connection string. Make sure the username and password in this file matches the credentials of your configured MYSQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar issue and after some trial and error, stumbled upon following solution.

1. Stop the XAMPP control panel.
2. Go to ..\XAMPP\mysql
3. Find **resetroot.bat** and execute it.
4. Proceed with entering random key when prompted.
5. Restart XAMPP control panel.

Now, when you try to connect to DVWA, the browser should land you on the Login Page.

Solution: The bat file clears the passwords for 'root' and 'pma' user.

Note: Make sure you have **$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ]= ''** in your **config.inc.php** file

Worked for me! Good Luck !!

PS: I encountered this issue after a successful DVWA site crawling using BurpSpider. i.e Everything was working fine and all of sudden I encountered mysql error. If anyone knows the root cause then explanation will be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow simple steps to solve the issue :

1. In XAMPP folder -> passwords.txt (In this file, check the password of mysql)
2. Then go to DVWA's config.inc.php Make sure the password in passwords.txt of mysql should match.
3. The error comes only if does not match. Use the same password in config.inc.php file as it is in password.txt file).

Now it works.